# No viable overloaded '=' al querer meter un objeto a un arreglo por medio de un apuntador, ¿por qué?

Tags: c++, array, poo, punteros

Al tratar de meter un objeto a un arreglo que se encuentra como atributo de una clase me marca que el error "No viable overloaded '='". Tenía entendido que los arreglos son apuntadores por lo que me hizo sentido meterle objetos por medio de un apuntador. ¿En qué me estoy equivocando?

```
#include <iostream>

class Objeto
{
  private:
  std::string name;
  public:
  Objeto():name(" ") {};
  Objeto(std::string nombre):name(nombre) {}
  ~Objeto() {}
};

class Caja
{
  private:
  Objeto *objetos;
  unsigned int size;
  int count;

  public:
  Caja(unsigned int sze):size(sze) 
  {
    objetos = new Objeto[5];
    count=0;
  }
  ~Caja()
  {
    delete [] objetos;
  }
  void add(Objeto* obj)
  {
    objetos[count]=obj; //Aquí marca el error
    count++;
  }
};

int main() 
{
  Caja caja1(5);
  Objeto *puntero1 = new Objeto("objeto1");
  caja1.add(puntero1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu arreglo es un array de objetos de la clase `objeto`, no un array de punteros de la clase `objeto`.

*Tenía entendido que los arreglos son apuntadores*

No es que tu array consista en punteros, si no que para poder identificar tu arreglo se utiliza un puntero que apunta al primer elemento del mismo, lo cuál es diferente. En tu caso `objetos` apunta al primer elemento de tu array de 5 objetos de la clase `objeto` que inicializas en tu constructor, y utilizas este puntero llamado `objetos` para poder acceder al array.

Si quieres asignarle el valor a un elemento del arreglo necesitas utilizar un objeto de la clase `objeto`, así:

```
objetos[count]=*obj;
```

De esta manera estamos accediendo al valor al que apunta el puntero, estamos utilizando un objeto y no el puntero a un objeto lo cuál es correcto, porque cómo dije antes, tu array es de objetos y no de punteros a objetos (me siento como escribiendo un trabalenguas).